# Laravel 5 HTTP/Requests - pass url parameter to the rules() method

Tags: laravel-routing, laravel-5, laravel-request

I'm trying to create a set of rules under the new `\HTTP\Requests\UpdateArticle` class for the `slug` field, which needs to have `unique` filter applied, but only when the `id` is not equal the url parameter of the route name `article/{article}`.

What I got so far is:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'title' => 'required|min:3',
        'excerpt' => 'required',
        'body' => 'required',
        'slug' => 'required|unique:articles,slug,?',
        'active' => 'required',
        'published_at' => 'required|date'
    ];

}
```

I need to replace the question mark at the end of the unique filter for `slug` field with the id from the url, but don't know how to obtain it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve route parameters by name with `input()`:

```
$id = Route::input('id');
return [
    // ...
    'slug' => 'required|unique:articles,id,' . $id,
    // ...
];
```

It's right [there in the docs](http://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#route-parameters) (scroll down to *Accessing A Route Parameter Value*)

Comment: you should share the docs link. Guys nowdays does not like to read: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/routing

Comment: Thanks - that seem to work fine. Also - is using Route facade inside of the Request class considered a good practice you think?

Comment: Although I'm not sure I think what you actually want is this rule: `'required|unique:articles,slug,'.$id.'`. Regarding the facade. I'd rather use dependency injection for that. Make sure to type hint `Illuminate\Routing\Router` and not `Route`

Comment: Thanks - that's what I thought - and yes - it was a slug not id in the filter - just forgotten to update the ticket.

Comment: As of Laravel 5.1, Class 'App\Http\Requests\Route' is not found or it may have been deprecated. And I can't see anyways to get URL parameters from the 5.1 documentation. How can we resolve this to get parameters from the URL?

Comment: @DonCadavona This class never existed. Just use the global alias.. `use Route;`

Comment: When I try to use Route::input('id'), it Laravel 5.1 returns this error: "Class 'App\Http\Requests\Route' is not found". How could that be?

Comment: @Don You have to **import** the class at the top with `use Request;`

Answer (score 2):

To get URL parameters from the URL:

```
$this->route('id');
```

A great discussion on this were also asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31493101/how-to-get-and-pass-url-parameters-to-classes-in-laravel-5-1/31497598).