# How to validate unique fields while updating in make:request in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5, laravel-validation, laravel-request

I'm developing a small application in `Laravel 5.5` where I'm creating a request with `updateContact` and having unique email validation rule, while using the same validation inside the controller I can easily make:

```
$contact = Contact::find($request->id);
Validator::make($data, [
    'first_name' => 'required|max:255',
    'email' => 'required', Rule::unique('contacts')->ignore($contact->id),
    'address' => 'max:255',
    'city' => 'max:255',
    'state' => 'max:255',
    'country' => 'max:255',
]);
```

and can validate, by I made out request through `php artisan make:request UpdateContact` and added the following inside `updateContact.php`:

```
namespace App\Http\Requests;

use App\Contact;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

class UpdateContact extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        $contact = Contact::find($request->id);
        return [
            'first_name' => 'required|max:255',
            'email' => 'required', Rule::unique('contacts')->ignore($contact->id),
            'company_id' => 'required',
            'address' => 'max:255',
            'city' => 'max:255',
            'state' => 'max:255',
            'country' => 'max:255',
        ];
    }

    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'company_id.required' => 'Company name is required'
        ];
    }
}
```

But I don't know about the `$request->id` how can I use this?

Comment: I'm not sure, but you could inject it as an attribute/parameter in the `rules()` method. Try `public function rules(Request $request)`. Then you could make `$request->id`

Comment: @HCK Laravel request itself is a `Request` as we take `use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;` this is the confusing part whether   to inject request again inside this?

Comment: you can access the current request using the [request](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-request) helper

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28530960/7117697

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside a FormRequest class, **$this** is the variable scope of the request object. Simply do the following to get the ID property

```
$contact = Contact::find($this->id);
```

Same goes for any other field in your form.

Answer (score 2):

**Why you are finding Contact with id again that you already have in Request object ?**

You can simply use this code:

```
 'email' => 'required', Rule::unique('contacts')->ignore($this->id),
```

You are using **id** to find **Contact** and then again using **$contact->id** that you already have in Request object that is **$this**.
You can simply use **$this->id** it will give you the id of the **Contact**. There is no need to write below line:

```
 $contact = Contact::find($this->id);
```

because

```
$this->id is same as $contact->id
```

You can also validate unique email using below code:

```
'email' => "required|unique:users,email,$this->id,id" //use double quotation marks
```

It will do the same as:

```
'email' => 'required', Rule::unique('contacts')->ignore($this->id),
```

Have a look at snippet that use in Request class

```
public function rules()
{
    switch ($this->method()) {
        case 'POST':
        {
            return [
                'name' => 'required',
                'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
                'password' => 'required'
            ];
        }
        case 'PUT':
        case 'PATCH':
        {
            return [
                'name' => 'required',
                'email' => "required|unique:users,email,$this->id,id"
                 //OR you can use below rule
                // 'email' => Rule::unique('users')->ignore($this->id),
            ];
        }
        default: break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To call object of the class within it you can use **$this** variable scope. and then access any variable that is part of the object. e.g
**$this->id**, **$this->name** etc.

If you want to access static function within same class then you can use **self** keyword.
for example you have a static function

```
public static function add($a, $b){
    return $a+$b;
}
```

you call **add** method like **self::add(2,2);**